# Fetch string arrays from json in angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to fetch string arrays from a json file and return the data back to a variable to form a word filer list, but "uncaught syntax error" kept showing can anyone help? Here comes my code:

```
    var filterWords = $http.get('word.json').success(function(res) {
      return angular.fromJson(res.data);
    });

    $scope.filterWord = function($string) {
         var wRegExp = new RegExp(filterWords.join("|"), "gi");
         return wRegExp.test($string);
    };
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no `syntax error` here. Some another part of your code causes an error.

Comment: plus, I am not sure that your code will work, you treat in the second function an async function as a sync function.

Comment: @Meir Does it mean that the data could be set to `filterWords` even after the `filterWord()` called?

Comment: It means that async calls usually set scope values (used by binding in the view) asynchronously

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do the `angular.fromJson` part, AngularJS does that for you. `res.data` will contain an object parsed from JSON if the result is JSON.

In the line `var wRegExp = new RegExp(filterWords.join("|"), "gi");` you are not waiting for the result of `filterWords`, so you are calling `join("|")` on an HTTP promise. I'm not sure what the structure of your code is since I can only see the two lines you've shown, but perhaps you meant to set a variable in the `success` handler? Or have the `success` handler in the `filterWord` function?

Comment: I need the data in the json file and set them to `filterWords` for `filterWord()`. Maybe I should have the success handler in the `filterWord` function?

Comment: Then I would change the name of `filterWords` to `filterWordsPromise` and instead of returning something in the `success` handler I would do something like `$scope.filterWord = res.data`. Keep in mind that since the call is asynchronous, `$scope.filterWord` will be undefined for a while, then be set to the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So your idea is to define `filterWord()` as an asyn function while synchronized with `$http.get` right?